# How to collect latest Queries?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to display the latest queries which have been run on my site using PHP

like

www.torrentz.com

We can see the latest searches..

So is this possible ?? to put it on my homepage ?

Comment: Can you give more informations please. Are you a CMS?

Comment: do you mean an auto-completion list based on what the user types?

Comment: @ynh "Are you a CMS?" Hardly.

Comment: @jensgram sorry I forgot the word "using"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store them in a database and then query that table to take a sample of the most recent queries.
Something like

```
SELECT * FROM recent_queries ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 20
```

Would select the most recent 20 queries providing you save a time stamp of when the original search was made.